# Submit form automatically if the URL has parameters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to submit a form automatically if the url has a parameter. The form is prefilled with the value of the parameter.

```
<form name="search" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input tabindex="1" type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" value="<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($_GET["item"]) != '') ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["item"]) : '';?>">
        <input type = "hidden" name = "doSearch" value = "1">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name = "submit"><i class="material-icons icon-button">search</i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I do that? I would only like to submit the form it if there is a paramter, otherwise not.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
www.test.com?item=example      --> submit prefilled form automatically

www.test.com    --> do nothing
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to do. Explain your project a bit more. You are talking about "load" and "submit" which are complete opposite terms. You also refer to submission of the form on `onload()`. Can you explain why you do that? Give us more details.

Comment: I want to automatically submit the form when the page is loading, but only if the url has parameters, otherwise not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how complex you want this to be, so here is a simple example.

**JavaScript**

```
function submitForm() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
    document.getElementsByName("search")[0].submit();
  }
}

submitForm();
```

This will only check if there is a query string separator in the url (which typically means that query strings are to follow the `?` mark).

So if you have `www.test.com?item=example` the form will be submitted. However, `www.test.com?` will also submit.

Let me know if that's a solution that works for you or not.

**EDIT:** You must rename the html elements with name `submit` and `search` to something else. You probably also need to add the `action` attribute to your `form`.

So you end up with something like this:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="form_handle.php">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input tabindex="1" type="text" name="search_input" class="form-control" placeholder="Item" value="<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($_GET["item"]) != '') ? htmlspecialchars($_GET["item"]) : '';?>">
      <input type = "hidden" name = "doSearch" value = "1">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name = "submit_btn"><i class="material-icons icon-button">search</i></button>
      </span>
   </div>
</form>

<script>
function submitCheck() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        document.getElementsByName("search")[0].submit();
    }
}

submitCheck();
</script>
```

Comment: In theory it should work, because there is no case in which the url has a ? only, but it actually it doesn't.

Comment: I forgot an "s" in `getElementsByName`. Fixed, so try again. Edit: I tested and it worked.

Comment: No it didn't. It doesn't submit the form. Also I have the problem, that I need to include the php script below and can't use the action. But I tried the action method too.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I copy-pasted the code I sent you and tried it on my server a 2nd time and it works perfectly. If url has `?` it submits form, otherwise it doesn't. Try it again. Copy-paste **everything** from the code above, and put it in empty file. Save, upload and test.

Comment: If it still doesn't work - send me the link to your site where you have the code.

Comment: The site is password-protected. But [here](http://pastebin.com/WRetRMbM) is a link to the code...

Comment: I need to see the post-processed code, not the pre-processed code (php). Press ctrl+u in brower and send that code instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me, because I have no action inside my form. What I would need is a script which clicks the search button when the url has a parameter.

Comment: You asked how you can submit a form automatically if a URL has  parameters. I have shown you how, and I've also spend quite a lot of time trying to see why my solution "wasn't working", even though it was. Now you want a script that clicks a button..

I understand this didn't solve all your problems, but I believe it did solve **what you asked**. I believe I have answered the question "Submit form automatically if the URL has parameters", and my solution should be marked as such.

You can still post a new question, and I'll be happy to help again. But this question has been answered.