# Submit form automatically if the URL has a specific parameter

Tags: forms

I have an existing form (for example with a class **.myform**) which would need to be submitted if there is a specific parameter in the URL (for example **?push_submit**). I've seen the existing article about this ([Submit form automatically if the URL has parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876128/submit-form-automatically-if-the-url-has-parameters)) but it seems not to be working. A quick note - I cannot add an action to the form as it is generated by a plugin.

Comment: `seems not to be working` ... what does that mean? ... does it work sometimes? ... what actually happens?

Comment: No, in my case it is not working - I'm referring to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876128/submit-form-automatically-if-the-url-has-parameters

Comment: _"it is not working"_ is not working because there is something not doing what *you expected, as opposed to what *you observed, so you'd need to describe "observed" vs "expected" instead